# What should a merchant site worry about when implementing a payment gateway?

Tags: c#, security, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I have to implement a payment gateway for a website I am maintaining, and I haven't done anything like this before. Previously to implement payment processing, the site would build a transaction and send it directly to the payment processor and await a result. Since the site handled the gathering of credit card information, building of the transaction, and the requests/responses, there wasn't much I had to worry about that the previous developer hadn't already covered.

Now that I'm implementing a payment gateway, is there anything I should be checking or verifying?

The way this processor works is, I build a form that has the order id, amount, currency, etc. in hidden fields. That form is posted to the gateway, which will handle the processing, and then post a form back to our server where we can update the shopping cart and complete the order.

The only thing I can think of is a user modifying the form fields before we post them to the gateway. Such as adding a $100 item and changing

```
<input name="amount" value="100.00" type="hidden">
```

to

```
<input name="amount" value="0.01" type="hidden">
```

So when I receive the post I have to verify that the amount paid for was equal to the amount owed. Is there anything else I am missing? The implementation documentation doesn't even mention a scenario similar to the above, so I'm a little worried I'm missing other things and leaving the site open to further exploits.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which gateway you're implementing.  Most gateway services provide support and code samples.  If yours doesn't, you might want to consider switching to one that does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off creating a dedicated web service to handle this '3rd party' conduit architecture you have going on here, your basically playing the middle-man and an HTML form just feels like unnecessary overhead to me, unless it's required to be done that specific way, I'd move to a web service.

That being said, treat it like any client application, don't trust whatever they give you, validate and cleanse the information as necessary before performing the operation.

I would also recommend building or integrating support for logging into your middle ware system, so should a problem arise, you have some way of capturing issues and tracking them for the future, bug fixes, support calls, etc.

It's probably obvious but make sure to validate your order #'s, a user could put anything in there they wanted, again, validate and cleanse the data and log the truly weird situations.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to agree with Capital G. It would be so much easier to just make a server to server connection than to try and handle form submission through the client browser.

One thing to check: after submitting to the gateway, does the client then initiate the post back to your server, or does the gateway server handle it? If the client initiates it, what prevents them from POSTing to you that the order is complete without ever having gone to the gateway? It sounds like you might need to make a webservice request to the gateway to verify the payment actually went through before accepting the client POST that claims it did.

Could you add a digest to the communication? If you had a shared secret with the gateway you could validate the integrity of information shared even if it passed through the client by including a digest both ways.

Make sense?

Carl

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think you're implementing a payment gateway. It sounds like you're just using one. If this is wrong, just ignore the rest of this answer, and I'll delete it when I can :)

**Using a Payment Gateway from a Simple HTTP Form**

Google Checkout -- as one example -- allows you to use an "unsigned cart" like the one you describe. The other option is to post via the web service interface, and do correct error checking etc.. When you submit an order with an HTML form, Google Checkout warns you, the merchant, that the "cart is unsigned" (later in the admin screen). This means that the information in the cart -- especially prices -- is not to be trusted. The fact that the end-user put in their credit card basically vouches for the fact that the transaction is okay with him/her. So you just have to check that the numbers used to arrive at the final totals -- or amount owed, or whatever your business is -- check out. So what you're doing is fine on a low-level.

The reason you should use a web-service submit to the service -- and secure signing of the cart, etc. -- is... What do you do if the numbers are wrong? Call the end-user up and explain the situation? So that's a bit tricky, because **you cannot assume fraud.** There are many strange reasons for which the cart would be altered without the user actually wanting to scam you.